# Баг в dataTable

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Помогите! У меня проблема: при добавлении следующей функции в datatable: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/stateSave.html , пропадает выбор количества строк таблицы, при том, что без этой строки

```
dom: 'Bfrtip'
```

всё работает нормально, но не работает сама функция. В чем проблема?

```
$("#table").dataTable({
                    responsive: true,
            colReorder: true,
                    language: {
                        "processing": "Подождите...",
                        "search": "Поиск:",
                        "lengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
                        "info": "Показано с _START_ до _END_ записей из _TOTAL_",
                        "infoEmpty": "Записи с 0 до 0 из 0 записей",
                        "infoFiltered": "(отфильтровано из _MAX_ записей)",
                        "infoPostFix": "",
                        "loadingRecords": "Загрузка записей...",
                        "zeroRecords": "Записи отсутствуют.",
                        "emptyTable": "В таблице отсутствуют данные",
                        "paginate": {
                        "first": "Первая",
                        "previous": "<",
                        "next": ">",
                        "last": "Последняя"
                        },
                        "aria": {
                        "sortAscending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по возрастанию",
                        "sortDescending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по убыванию"
                        }
                    },
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "aLengthMenu": [[ 3, 10, 20, 50, 100 ,-1],[ 3, 10,20,50,100,"все"]],
                    stateSave: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            stateSave: true,
            buttons: [
                'colvis'
            ],
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто.
Отталкиваясь от документации https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom, мы видим, что `l` вы не выводите в `dom`.
Как вариант, написать так:

```
dom: 'Blfrtip'
```

Или так:

```
dom: 'lBfrtip'
```

P.S. С datatables никогда не работал, но, если интересно, решение, погуглив, нашел здесь: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38909/adding-excel-export-button-hides-removes-the-page-length-dropdown

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я уже на самом сайте вопрос задавал.